# Set Width based on other control Width

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

I am trying to set the `Width` of an image of 600px width, based on the `Width` of another control in the same `Grid` column (`Grid.Column="0"`). Is there a way where I can capture the `Width` of that element (`MenuControl`) and put that number in the image `Width` to get a lower value than 600px?

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
      <Image Source="/Assets/combanc.png" Margin="10" Width="{Binding ElementName=MenuControl, Path=ActualWidth}" />
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: you can try ValueConverter

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to bind the size of another control, but the image should not exceed a maximum size of `600`, regardless of the size of the other control. You can create a value converter that returns the minimum of the bound size and a parametrized maximum.

```
public class MaximumSizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      if (!(value is double size) ||
          !(parameter is string maximumText) ||
          !double.TryParse(maximumText, out var maximum))
         return Binding.DoNothing;

      return Math.Min(size, maximum);
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new InvalidOperationException();
   }
}
```

Then you can create an instance of the converter in a resource dictionary in scope, e.g. `Grid.Resources` and use it in the `Width` binding of `Image`. Specify the converter by referencing it in the `Converter` property and set the maximum as `ConverterParameter`.

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.Resources>
      <local:MaximumSizeConverter x:Key="MaximumSizeConverter"/>
   </Grid.Resources>
   <!-- ...your other markup. -->
   <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
      <Image Source="/Assets/combanc.png" Margin="10" Width="{Binding ElementName=MenuControl, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource MaximumSizeConverter}, ConverterParameter=600}" />
   </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I will try it, but this whole WPF MVVM is overcomplicated, thats why I like Winforms more but it have a lot of problems with dpi scaling and resizing